# Netbeans wont pull using bitbucket

Tags: git, netbeans-7, bitbucket

I keep getting this every time, its been happening alot frequently. how do i fix this. every forum i find says to type in commands on git... were is this mystery console, i cant seem to find it or anything people are saying.

```
==[IDE]== May 19, 2013 5:24:00 PM Pulling...
git pull https://bitbucket.org/techreanimate/project
+refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/project/master
Branch  : project/master
Old Id : 6fdea249fc80641a1b3e63174e7dd4ec6b72d84d
New Id : a19141fea8cbc7a64553b84ed6b591e223384b7a
Result : FAST_FORWARD

Merge Result: Failed
Merge of HEAD with project/master failed because of these files:
A:\Dev\project\Workspace\project-Web\.htaccess

==[IDE]== May 19, 2013 5:24:03 PM Pulling... finished.
```

oh, its not always .htaccess, its random files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Were is this mystery console

When plugin using git (like the IDE NetBeans) fails, it is best to fall back to that console.
Specifically, to a separate installation of git, to see if you reproduce the issue.

In windows, for instance, download and unzip an archive of [msysgit portable](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list?can=2&q=portable&colspec=Filename%20Summary%20Uploaded%20ReleaseDate%20Size%20DownloadCount).

Then try a `git pull` from your working tree, and see what the *exact* error message is.

[Sych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1818256/sych) emphasizes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16639632/netbeans-wont-pull-using-bitbucket/18432285?noredirect=1#comment27134117_18432285) (after Sych's [own upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18462596/6309)):

> **USE A DIFFERENT GIT CLIENT TO INITIALIZE THE REPO, then continue to use NetBeans**

---

Also, [make sure you can see and access your `.gitignore` and `.htaccess`](http://prattski.com/2011/04/25/netbeans-display-gitignore-file-in-projectsfiles/) (two dotfiles usually ignored by netbeans)

> Netbeans preferences, go to the the Miscellaneous tab at the top, then click on the Files tab. You’ll see a “Files Ignored by the IDE” section there.

```
^(CVS|SCCS|vssver.?\.scc|#.*#|%.*%|_svn)$|~$|^\.(?!(htaccess|gitignore)$).*$
```

That way, you can see how the git plugin treats those files.

Comment: This answer gets the bounty, just to emphasize the solution: 
USE A DIFFERENT GIT CLIENT TO INITIALIZE THE REPO, then continue to use NetBeans

Comment: @Sych Ok, I have added your emphasis in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: i switched over to Aptana long ago. using git cli for it. But it has a native git terminal right in the ide as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have ended up installing Tortoise GIT to initially fetch the repo to NetBeans project folder, after that I use NetBeans to sync files with the remote repo with no problem.

Comment: Good workaround, which you could have achieve too with the msysgit console I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18432285/6309). +1

Answer (score 0):

You have changed or created `.htaccess` file and didn't commit it.

If you are not ready to commit do git stash & git pull & git stash pop then resolve a conflict.

Or you can commit your changes then pull then reslove your conflict.

Comment: no, i never changed the file, and there is no option to stash in netbeans. like i said. random files that i haven't touched in ages

Comment: Use console, it's not so hard.

Comment: there is no console, all there is, is terminal. and git commands dont work

Comment: forget it, i switched to aptana